# Generating a ListView Using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to populate a `ListView` using an `ArrayAdapter` that I am filling with input from an `EditText`. My program seems to compile fine but during app start up it immediately crashes. I suspect that it has something to do with me trying to set-up my list view. I am not sure what I am initializing wrong such that my app instantly crashes. Any and all tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my global declarations for my `ArrayList` and `Adapter`.

```
ArrayList<scoreScreen> savedScores = new ArrayList<>();
ScoreAdapter adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, savedScores);

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dispScores);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My Adapter Class:

```
 private class ScoreAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<scoreScreen> {
    private ScoreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<scoreScreen> scores) {
        super(context, 0, scores);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        scoreScreen score1 = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_scores, parent, false);
        }
        TextView holeNum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holeNum);
        holeNum.setText(score1.hole);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My `ListView` inside of my `onCreate` method.

```
 ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am assuming my problem is not inside my `EditText` inputs since they are inside of an `OnClickListener` method, but just incase I have attached it below.

```
public View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.scorePrompt);
        TextView output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTotal);
        String blankCheck = input1.getText().toString(); //CHANGE INPUT IN scorePrompt TO STRING
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttTotal:
                    if (blankCheck.equals("")) {
                        Toast blankError = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOU CANT SKIP HOLES JERK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        blankError.show();
                        break;
                     } else {
                        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.getText().toString()); //Get input from text box
                        int sum = num1 + score2;
                        score2 = sum;
                        output1.setText("Your score is : " + Integer.toString(sum));
                        //savedScores.add(input1.getText().toString());

                        scoreScreen addScore = new scoreScreen("Score is" + num1);
                        adapter.add(addScore);
                        j++;
                        input1.setText(""); //Clear input text box
                        break;
                    }
            case R.id.allScores: //CHANGE THIS TO AN EDIT BUTTON, ADD A HOLE NUMBER COUNTER AT TOP OF SCREEN!!!!!
                output1.setText("you messed up");
                break;
            case R.id.editScore: //Need to set up Save Array before we can edit
                //CURRENTLY ONLY DISPLAYS THE LAST NUNMBER IN THE TEXTEDIT, NEED TO SET UP LISTVIEW!!!!!!
                for (int i=0; i < j; i++){
                //    output1.setText(savedScores.get(i));
                } break;
        }
    }
};
```

`onCreate` method added as requested:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*Button scoresAct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.allScores);   //THIS IS TO GO TO ALL SCORES ACTIVITY
    scoresAct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent scoreScreen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AllScoresAct.class);
            startActivity(scoreScreen);
        }
    });*/

    Button sumScores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttTotal);
    Button saveScores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.allScores);
    Button changeScores = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editScore);
    sumScores.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    saveScores.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    changeScores.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

After moving my adapter and ArrayList into my `onCreate`, I get a new error. I did some research on null pointers, but I have already initialized both of these. Below is my logcat, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: put your stacktrace here with the errors

Comment: What is at `MainActivity.java` line 21? You cannot create a `new ScoreAdapter ` outside of the onCreate method

Comment: It was because my adapter was declared outside of my `onCreate`. I have since moved it but am now receiving a null pointer error but I am not sure why as I believe I have properly initialized everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is my global declarations for my ArrayList and Adapter.
>
> ```
> ArrayList<scoreScreen> savedScores = new ArrayList<>();
> ScoreAdapter adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, savedScores);
> ```

You can **declare** those globally, but for the Adapter, the `this` parameter must be used within/after `onCreate`, as the error says

> System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

For example

```
private ArrayList<ScoreScreen> savedScores = new ArrayList<>();
private ScoreAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    ...

    adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, savedScores);
}
```

Comment: I have since moved both my `ArrayList` and my `adapter` into the my `onCreate` but the app is still crashing upon startup. Furthermore, I am receiving an error when I am attempting to add into my `ArrayList` during my `OnClickListener` method (this happens whether or not my `ArrayList` is declared inside of my `onCreate` or globally. Any ideas why?

Comment: Well, this specific code fixes the initial error. I can't answer why else your app crashes without seeing your stacktraces

Comment: I have added in the logcat to my main post. It seems like my ListArray was not properly initialized but I cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: Well, typically that error arises when you use findViewById on an XML layout that doesn't actually contain the id you're looking for. That's explained in the documentation of the findViewById method return types

Comment: Hi cricket! You are exactly right! I was going back and forth between my xml and java files and found that I was incorrectly referencing a `ListView` id in the wrong xml.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` is the first thing you are calling in your onCreate() and also not trying to access any view from the layout xml before `setContentView()`.

EDIT:

Initialize the adapter in `onCreate()` method instead of doing it globally.

```
onCreate() {
   .......
   this.adapter = new ScoreAdapter(this, savedScores);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to SO. I have updated my question to include my `onCreate` as well. Not sure if you get a notification of this but if you do and I am bothering you I am sorry!

Comment: Updated the answer.